# How to parameterize secrets on GitHub Action

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

We have two branches in repository (dev/prd), each representing a deployment environment. Also we have GitHub action secrets for each branch, in dev branch it should be dev_react_api, in prd branch it should be prd_react_api.

Now we are working on a GitHub action workflow using these secrets secrets.dev_react_api and secrets.prd_react_api

Is there a solution to parameterize GitHub action secrets like the following ?

```
# only pseudo-code
env:
  branch_name: github.ref

secrets["${env.branch_name}_react_api"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work exactly like you have shown with the dynamic name. `secrets` is just a variable and you provide the key name either explicitly `secrets.x` implicitly `secrets['x']`. Building your key dynamicly works just fine as such. The additional env `branch_name` is also unneeded since you can just get that value directly in the string.

If you have a paid GitHub plan or are using a public repo, you can also take a look at [Environments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environments) which take care of this entirely by instead defining two separate environments with the required secrets each.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. sadly get a "Unexpected symbol" error when I try to do secrets["x"]

Comment: Ah sorry, only works with `'` instead of `"`. Also fixed in the answer. So use `secrets['x']`, where `x` is your env variable

Comment: thanks for the comment. sorry that another question pops up.  it seems to be not possible to refers to environment variable within secrets context, because secrets["${env.branch_name}_react_api"] gives me an empty string

Comment: Not sure if you can reference env variables from GH Actions internal blocks, since env is already at the lower runner level. You might need to solely work with the github.ref wtithin the secrets retrieval too. Also keep in mind that github.ref has the format `refs/heads/main`, so you will need to clean that up before you use it

Comment: thanks a lot for the effort. the reference problem is solved by using ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/dev' && secrets['DEV_AWS_S3_BUCKET'] || secrets['PRD_AWS_S3_BUCKET'] }}

Comment: FYI - Referencing without quotes like so `secrets[x]` is the only thing that worked in my case. Putting either single or double quotes around x would not work, the result would simply be empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`format` filter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#format) to concatenate the secret name inline.

A general example would be `format('Hello {​​0}! I am {1}!', 'world', 'templated')`, which will yield `Hello World! I am templated!`.

Your example thus should work like this:

```
secrets[format('{0}_react_api', env.branch_name)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Environment Secrets for that.

First Goto: Settings -> Environments -> New Environment

Create a new environment and MAKE SURE your environment name matches your branch name

[image: Environment Secrets]

Now you can create any environment secrets that you want, now the trick is, you need two files to use Environment Secrets. First is the main.yml and the second is your (for example) deploy.yml

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
    - staging
    - development
    
permissions: write-all

jobs:  
  deploy:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/deploy.yml
    with:
      environment: ${{ github.ref_name }}
    secrets:
      AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET }}
```

The second files that USES the environment:

```
name: Deployment


on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      environment:
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:
      AWS_S3_BUCKET:
        required: true


jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    environment: ${{ github.ref_name }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
        name: Deploy to S3
        env:
          AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET }}
        with:
          args: --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete
```

Now you can create any number of environments with different parameters!

For more details see: [https://github.com/olivatooo/github-actions-build-deploy-with-staging-production-environment/](https://github.com/olivatooo/github-actions-build-deploy-with-staging-production-environment/blob/main/README.md)

Comment: I can't see environments in my repository settings